# What kind of academic social networks does mathematicians use?

Tags: soft-question

I am interested in signing up for academic social network like Mendeley, ResearchGate, Academia.edu where

- I can read papers published by mathematicians.
- Allows to publish papers.
- Allows to collaborate with other mathematicians.

**I am interested in a such network where majority of mathematicians use.**
I did a google search but no luck.

Comment: maybe the one cornell arXiv.org or something like that.

Comment: Since it is an archive, not a network it only support reading.

Comment: I'm sure there is no "network which a majority of mathematicians use"

Comment: Indeed, the lack of "Like" button can be seen as a serious disadvantage in these days. Other than that, arxiv is the network you are after.

Comment: I was wondering why arXiv.org is so popular among you guys

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/284954/what-kind-of-academic-social-networks-do-mathematicians-use

Comment: I think because it is more liberal to allowing publishing of papers, which also means yes there are probably some poor ones. But one can argue any publishing organisation has that. I believe Andrew Lisey exceptional simple e8 group theory of everything used arxiv.org, as well Gregory Pearlman for Poincare conjecture. So I think there is feedback, though maybe not directly built in, if your papers are interesting to someone.

Comment: Also im not aware of popular mathematician dating websites?